# WPF reload current UserControl on button click

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to reload the current UserControl after inserting a record to create another record without going to the Main Form on button click in the same UserControl

the ContentControl on main form already made it Public
here is XAML code:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="mainContentControl" x:FieldModifier="public" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Background="#FFB9B9B9" Foreground="#B9B9B9" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
```

and here is the UserControl add new button code:

```
private void New_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

           MainFrm.mainContentControl.Clear();
           TechData_uc frm = new TechData_uc();
           frm.Width = 1050.376;
           MainFrm.mainContentControl.Content = frm;


        }
```

but i got error said : 
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainFrm.mainContentControl'

Note :
the New_btn_Click is in UserControl and the XAML is in the Main Form
can you help me ?

Comment: it's not clear about all your xaml structure.. .what happens if you remvoe the MainFrm. from those two places?

Comment: the New_btn_Click is in UserControl and the XAML is in the Main Form

Comment: use a view model and reset that

Comment: I suspect you don't have an instance of the main form but are using the class name. But @DanielA.White is suggesting a better path for you.

Comment: can you give me example of code @ Daniel A. White